# Backbone, parse JSON and then how do I trigger render?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Today is my first day of `backbone.js` so go easy on me here. 
I have a `view`, a `collection` and a `model` that populate a `select`.

I can populate the `select` fine with a **hardcoded** `array`.  But I'm using an existing API and I need to parse the response first.  This seems to work ok too.

What I don't know is who to tell what's changed in order to render my newly returned results/models...  The code should make more sense If that didn't help.

```
var UserGroup = Backbone.Model.extend();

var UserGroups = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize:function(){
        this.fetch();
    },

    model: UserGroup,

    url: "http://myAPI/getUserGroups",

    parse: function(json){

        return json["GetUserGroups"]["Results"];
    }

});

var GroupSelectView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("select"),

    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.collection = new UserGroups();

        this.render();

    },

    render: function(){
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(group){
            $("<option/>", { value: group.get("Id"), text: group.get("Name")} ).appendTo(this.el)
        }, this);
    },
});

var groupSelectView = new GroupSelectView();
```

What do you reckon?  Am I getting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be a bit more flexible you could listen to `reset` and `add` events.

The collection is `reset` when you `fetch` it from the server (or locally) but if you `add` models or `fetch` with the `add` option, an add event for each model is fired instead.

[Backbone.js:fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

This should work:

```
var GroupSelectView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.setElement($("select"));
        this.collection = new UserGroups();

        // listen to add and reset events but handle them differently
        // fired on collection.add(model) and collection.fetch({add: true})
        this.collection.on("add", this.renderItem, this);
        // fired on collection.fetch()
        this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);

    },

    render: function(){
        // backbone collections already come with some underscore methods built in
        this.collection.each(this.renderItem, this);
    },

    renderItem: function(group) {
        this.$el.append($("<option/>", {
            value: group.get("Id"),
            text: group.get("Name")})
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the fallowing...

```
var GroupSelectView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("select"),

    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;

        this.collection = new UserGroups();
        this.collection.on( 'change', this.render, this );


    //  You could try this too, 1 is for 1 item is added, the other, when all items are changed
    //  this.postCollection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
    //  this.postCollection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);

        this.render();

    },

    render: function(){
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(group){
            $("<option/>", { value: group.get("Id"), text: group.get("Name")} ).appendTo(this.el)
        }, this);
    },
});
```

Comment: I tried this orignally but the change event isnt being fired, or am I supposed to manually trigger it?

Comment: like this:  this.fetch({success: function(){that.trigger("change")}});

Comment: @CrimsonChin is fired when the object change (in this case the UserGroup Collection) on a fetch or a reset it will trigger the change event, so, it will call the render method

Comment: `change` is only fired on models, not on the collection itself. If a model changes, then it propagates to its collection. When a collection is fetched, a `reset` event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) to publish/subscribe changes. Follow the link for more information.

Models and Collections have inbuilt events that are fired for common use cases such as attributes of a model getting changed ('change') and a Collection's models fetched ('reset').

To trigger a change (Publish):

> myObject.trigger('event');

To subscribe to a change (Subscriber)

```
myObject.on('event',myCallback,context);
```

Set myCallback to the render method of your view.

Check out [this post](http://aaronhardy.com/javascript/javascript-architecture-backbone-js-events/) for more details on Backbone Events.